# Opening vscode file from terminal hangs

Tags: visual-studio-code, homebrew

I'm running MacOS Catalina and I've installed `visual-studio-code` via Homebrew. When I run the `code` command my terminal hangs indefinitely and nothing happens.

I've tried re-installing VScode, the code command itself, and re-installing the command through the VScode UI as shown in the second image.

How can I get the code command to run without hanging?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `code` command calls `python` which I didn't have installed correctly. Check that the `python` command runs correctly.